# I read file then write the file and the spaces between text disappear

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner, stringbuilder

Im reading from a temp file and writing it to a permanent file but somewhere the string loses all its spaces

```java
    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String b, filename;
        b = null;
        filename = (textfieldb.getText());
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            dispose();
            Scanner scan;
            scan = new Scanner(new File("TempSave.txt"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                sb.append(scan.next());
            }
            b = sb.toString();
                    String c; 
        c = b;
        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(filename + ".txt");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(hiudsjh.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        pw.print(c);
        pw.close();
        System.out.println(c);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
          dispose();
        hiudsjh x = new hiudsjh();
        x.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

theres no error messages just the output should be a file with the spaces remaining

Comment: Can you please put together a minimal example? This code is in no state to run

Comment: this is a snippit from my code but like the temp file will say "whats up" for example then i write that to a file and its still "whats up" then when i open and write it to a new file in this code it becomes "whatsup" instead.

is that what ur asking?

Comment: What I’m saying is I can’t copy/paste this code at home and hack on it to find the issue. And putting your entire codebase here would be nonsense. So spend some time boiling down the issue to a small example that reproduces your problem. I could probably do it just by reading the code; in the process you and I would spot the issue

Comment: In `scan.hasNext()` there you are only scanning the strings while `sb.append(scan.next())` so you only add the string you are scanning without the empty space. I would recommend you to use another class like `FileInputStream`. Or make a loop like `while(File != null)`-

Comment: there's no reason for using a `Scanner`, is it? same for `StringBuilder` and probably for `PrintWriter` (kind of paradox to use a `StringBuilder` to write into a `*Writer` that already has that *building* {streaming} functionality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `hasNext()` and `next()` with which you don't get the spaces, use `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` to read the filr line by line and append after each line a line separator:

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    sb.append(scan.nextLine());
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, did fix it

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(scan.next());
}
```

is what is removing the spaces...`next()` will return the next complete token from the scanner, this does not include spaces. You will need to append spaces or change the way you read the file...

Answer (score 0):

From the Scanner [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

And from the [next methods docu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

In other words, the Scanner splits the input String into sequences without whitespaces. To read the file as a String you could use `new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` to read the entire file.

Comment: ahh ok thanks, sorry if my code looks stupid its my first time trying this stuff out

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scannining each token, you can read your file line by line and append a line separator after each line:

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    sb.append(scan.nextLine());
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
}
```